Fully confined incompressible fluid patterns under viscosity
Assume there is some energy in a closed 2d domain $\Omega$ depending on the velocity $v$ and a constant $K$:
$$ E=\int d\Omega\, K (\nabla v : \nabla v) $$
so that any spatial variation of $v$ is penalized. Or any other energy with a penalty on the variations of $v$. This is actually viscosity.
Let's assume that the fluid is incompressible: $\nabla.v=0$.
Is there a way or some litterature to determine the different modes of the patterns.
I mean that the least energy would be given by $v=0$ everywhere.
Then if the velocity is non-zero due to some force, a vortex should appear.
Increasing the energy would create a second vortex, and so on...
Of course the first vortex can also deform.
This sounds like the onset of a 2d turbulence, but in a close domain.
What would be the best models to study this hierarchy ?
